# RE: Mail Merge Google Sheet - Default subject line & Time trigger

Tags: google-sheets, mailmerge

Thanks in advance for your assistance here. I really appreciate it!!

I have built a script using the template here: https://developers.google.com/workspace/solutions/mail-merge
...And it's awesome. Working perfectly and solving a big problem for me!!

**I have 2 problems I need to fix, and I need your help, please!!**

**Problem 1:** Can I use a column (or cell reference) as a default "subjectLine" rather than it be user input each time the script is run?

**Problem 2:** Once Problem 1 (above) is solved, I'd like to trigger the script to automatically run every 15 minutes, continuously.

Any tips/scripts/pointers would be awesome. I am quite new to coding so have tried to dig up how to replace the user input piece of code with a default value for the subject line, but I can't figure it out. And only once this is done, can I then start to try and get code working for the second problem - so I'm stuck on both counts.

Thanks again!! Kind regards, Tom

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to focus each question to a single specific issue. I'd suggest editing out your `Problem 2` and post that separately (or, maybe better, take a look at [time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) and try to solve it yourself first). Also, can you please provide the relevant parts of the code you are using? (I know you are using that example script, but it contains many irrelevant stuff).

Comment: Thank you - I will do so in a moments time. Thanks for the advice!